# Filter data in input fields. Javascript array comparsion?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've got three input fields and a button. Into the fields only numbers, and commas can be typed. The result must be the numbers which are exactly occuring twice, in all the three fields. For example.

```
num_array1 = [1,2,3];
num_array2 = [1,2,3,4];
num_array3 = [1,5,6];
```

According to this example, the result should be: 2,3
The real trouble is the number "1", because all the arrays have it. With a simple embedded for cycle I can't do it, so I hope you can :) I expect any alternative, solution.

Some of my code:

```html
<body>

  <form name="numbers" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="number_1">
    <input type="text" id="number_2">
    <input type="text" id="number_3">
    <button id="evaluate" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
  </form>
  <p id="error"></p>
  <p id="result"></p>

</body>

<script>
  var number1 = document.getElementById("number_1").value.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '');
  var number2 = document.getElementById("number_2").value.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '');
  var number3 = document.getElementById("number_3").value.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '');

  var error = document.getElementById("error").innerHTML;
  var result = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;

  function myFunction() {
    if (isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2) || isNaN(number3)) {
      error = "Not legal character";
    } else {}
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution. First of all, you have to use `.split()` method in order to turns a `string` to an `array`.

```
var number1 = document.getElementById("number_1").value.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '').split(',');
//number1=[1,2,3]
```

Then you have to concat all 3 `array` and find only `number` which are exactly occuring twice, using `.concat()` method.

```
concatArray=number1.concat(number2,number3);
//concatArray=[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,5,6];
```

The next step is to find `number` of `occurences` of a specified `element` using `filter()` function.

If this number is `2` and the `element` not exists in the final `array`, then we will add it in `final` array, called `arr`.

To find out if `element` exists in `array`, we should use `indexOf()` method.

```js
var error = document.getElementById("error").innerHTML;
  var result = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
  var arr=[];
  function myFunction() {
      var number1 = document.getElementById("number_1").value.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '').split(',');
  var number2 = document.getElementById("number_2").value.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '').split(',');
  var number3 = document.getElementById("number_3").value.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '').split(','); 
      var concatArray=number1.concat(number2,number3);
    console.log(concatArray);
      for(i=0;i<concatArray.length;i++){
          var length=concatArray.filter(function(item){
              return item==concatArray[i];
          }).length;
          if(length==2 && arr.indexOf(concatArray[i])==-1){
             arr.push(concatArray[i]);
          }
      }
    console.log(arr);
  
  }
```

```html
<body>

  <form name="numbers" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="number_1">
    <input type="text" id="number_2">
    <input type="text" id="number_3">
    <button id="evaluate" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
  </form>
  <p id="error"></p>
  <p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this using Javascript. I am not including the code from UI but only showing the Javascript part.

It works in following steps.

1. Merging the Array into 1 array using Spread operator.
2. Using the GroupBy Custom function (from [here](http://var%20num_array1%20=%20[1,2,3];%20var%20num_array2%20=%20[1,2,3,4];%20var%20num_array3%20=%20[1,5,6];%20var%20resultArray%20=%20[];%20%20//%20Using%20the%20Spread%20Operator%20merging%20the%20Array%20into%20a%20Single%20Array.%20var%20combinedNumArray%20=%20[...num_array1,...num_array2,%20...num_array3];%20%20//%20Group%20By%20number%20var%20groupByNumbers%20=%20groupBy(combinedNumArray,%20i%20=%3E%20i);%20%20//%20Filter%20where%20count%20=%202%20groupByNumbers.forEach(function(value,%20key)%20%7B%20%20%20%20if(value.length%20===%202)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resultArray.push(key);%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D);%20%20console.log(resultArray);%20%20//%20Using%20a%20GroupBy%20Function%20//%20Borrowed%20from%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)) to group the Numbers so that count operation can be done. This returns a `Map` object
3. Filtering the `Map` obtained in above step where the criteria (count == 2) is met.

```js
var num_array1 = [1,2,3];
var num_array2 = [1,2,3,4];
var num_array3 = [1,5,6];
var resultArray = [];

// Using the Spread Operator merging the Array into a Single Array.
var combinedNumArray = [...num_array1,...num_array2, ...num_array3];

// Group By number
var groupByNumbers = groupBy(combinedNumArray, i => i);

// Filter where count = 2
groupByNumbers.forEach(function(value, key) {
   if(value.length === 2) {
       resultArray.push(key);
   }
});

console.log(resultArray);

// Using a GroupBy Function
// Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects
function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
    const map = new Map();
    list.forEach((item) => {
        const key = keyGetter(item);
        if (!map.has(key)) {
            map.set(key, [item]);
        } else {
            map.get(key).push(item);
        }
    });
    return map;
}
```